# DBF number Formatting C#

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

I create DBF File with c# and oledb , the files are correcte and are filled perfectly, no problem at all. I just a very tiny issue with it , it's that when i open those dbf files, all int values ​​contains zero at the end, so instead of '1' i found a '1.0000' . is there a way to erase those zeros?

here's the code that create and fill the table :

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            /*  Creation    Des  Tables   DBF   */

            //Create ptemp_param
            cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE test1( code int ,  
                                                    type varchar(50),   
                                                     nr int , 
                                                     name varchar(50) , 
                                                     date1 date)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            int  day, month, year, dow, endmonth;

            DateTime   date1;


            //Filling & Sending   Param & Deleting it


            foreach (string line in lines)
            {


                string[] split = line.Split('|');


                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into test1 values (" + split[0] + ",'" + split[1] + "'," + split[2] + ",'" + split[3] + "','" + split[4]  + "')";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: 1. Use parametrized queries. 2. What do you mean with "open those dbf files"?

Comment: i Opend the files with excel

Comment: @Dennis I used parametrized queries and no change at all ,

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the table as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE test1( code int ,  
                                                type varchar(50),   
                                                 nr int(10), 
                                                 name varchar(50) , 
                                                 date1 date)";
```

Note the change at the definition of `nr`. Set the value accordingly, as it limits the amount you can insert.

After some googling around, I found out .DBF-files belong to dBase, which has a slightly different syntax (see below).

```
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE test1( code int ,  
                                                type varchar(50),   
                                                 nr numeric(10,0), 
                                                 name varchar(50) , 
                                                 date1 date)";
```

Comment: I tried your method but i got an error "Syntax error in the create Table "

Comment: I used your way and nothing changed, I amstarting to have doubt that something wrong with my debugger! @StefanM

Comment: @SKGeek can you upload an example of your dbf file somewhere and post back a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

by using .DBF files. Are you working with Foxpro tables?  If so, I would suggest using Microsoft's Visual Foxpro OleDB provider instead of Jet.  It might be better at supporting proper "int" values.